# Iterating through JSON object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, loops, each

Since I'm fairly new to JSON and jQuery I'm struggling to iterate through an object I've sofar been able to load with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: source,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(obj) {
        // Laat een succes-melding zien wanneer de data goed ingeladen is
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function(obj) {
        // Laat een error-melding zien wanneer de data niet goed ingeladen is
        alert("ERROR");
    },
    complete: function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);           
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the structure of the JSON is a little bit complex for my taste, but since it's an external source (through YQL) nothing can be changed about this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
   "created": "2013-06-21T11:42:57Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "diagnostics": {
      "publiclyCallable": "true",
      "url": {
        "execution-start-time": "1",
        "execution-stop-time": "1868",
        "execution-time": "1867",
        "proxy": "DEFAULT",
        "content": "contentsource"
      },
      "user-time": "1868",
      "service-time": "1867",
      "build-version": "37740"
    },
    "results": {
      "viewentries": {
        "toplevelentries": "0",
        "viewentry": [
          {
            "date": "2013-06-11",
            "noteid": "A2FA",
            "position": "1",
            "siblings": "0",
            "unid": "15D7F7A15C0DAE",
            "entrydata": [
              {
                "columnnumber": "0",
                "name": "Datum_van_instantie",
                "text": "2013-06-11"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "1",
                "name": "kopregel",
                "text": "Title of newsitem 1"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "2",
                "name": "tussenkopje",
                "text": "Introduction text of newsitem 1"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "3",
                "name": "broodtekst",
                "text": "Content of newsitem 1"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "4",
                "name": "imagetag",
                "text": "Image URL of newsitem 1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "2013-05-29",
            "noteid": "A2F6",
            "position": "2",
            "siblings": "0",
            "unid": "9237CD3822ED8DD",
            "entrydata": [
              {
                "columnnumber": "0",
                "name": "Datum_van_instantie",
                "text": "2013-05-29"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "1",
                "name": "kopregel",
                "text": "Title of newsitem 2"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "2",
                "name": "tussenkopje",
                "text": "Introduction text of newsitem 2"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "3",
                "name": "broodtekst",
                "text": "Content of newsitem 2"
              },
              {
                "columnnumber": "4",
                "name": "imagetag",
                "text": "Image URL of newsitem 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
   }
  }
}
```

The thing I'd like to accomplish is to print something similar to the following to an element in my HTML file:

```
Title of newsitem 1
Title of newsitem 2
```

I'm sure from then on I am good to extract the rest of the items from the file. With the things I'm trying that makes sense to me, using an $.each loop on various obj.viewentry[0] alternatives I get an undefined error. When I try to access more specific e.g.

```
$.each(obj.viewentry, function(index, value) {
    console.log(this.entrydata[0]);             
});
```

The return I get is a jQuery error, TypeError: e is undefined. Although I'm fairly sure the last code is way too 'jQuery for Dummies', other answers I've been searching for this morning haven't really given me any more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$.each(obj.query.results.viewentries.viewentry, function (index, value){
    $.each(value.entrydata, function (index, value) {
        if (value.name == "kopregel") console.log(value.text);
    });
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/8tKYd/2/

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use jQuery for this (except for the ajax part):

```
for (var viewEntryKey in obj.query.results.viewentries.viewentry) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.query.results.viewentries.viewentry[viewEntryKey].entrydata.length; i++) {
        if (obj.query.results.viewentries.viewentry[viewEntryKey].entrydata[i].name == 'kopregel') {
            console.log(obj.query.results.viewentries.viewentry[viewEntryKey].entrydata[i].text);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Title of newsitem 1
>   Title of newsitem 2